# How to extract title, image from others' blog posts and publish on own site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm planning to build a site where I can share my handpicked curated contents and I couldn't wrap my head around the basic idea of getting those data fed into my site without going through API.

I first thought maybe I should inspect the source HTML of the page I want to embed on my site and access it with something like `$('div.post').find('img').attr('src')`.
But I can't imagine myself doing that every time so I guess there must be a better way.

It's what Google+ does with their post. Once you add a url link, after a second it pulls featured image and some text snippet from the linked page.

Comment: While this sounds like it would be perfect for javascript/jquery, cetain people of dubious repute use this for their nefarious reasons, so browsers lock it down and you have to enable it on the remote server (which you are unlikely to have access to).  Read more about cross-site-scripting here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

Comment: You can make a server-side call, but you've not mentioned your server-side tech (eg asp.net-mvc / php).  The code will also be slughtly different for every source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many sites use the [Open graph protocol](http://ogp.me/) to get the meta-title, meta-description, image etc. for any url.

For example open: view-source:https://blog.kissmetrics.com/open-graph-meta-tags/ and search for "Open Graph Protocol Meta".

They are contained in the page source. You will have to send a request to the URL you want to crawl from, and read the appropriate meta tags through Regular Expr / HTML Parsers.

Comment: Thanks. I've read the article you shared. So, is it doable with javascript only?

Comment: You cannot do it with front-end javascript, due to Cross origin policy as @freedomn-m has said. You need to send the web request from a server side language, say Java/PHP/Py/NodeJS. If you are familiar with Nodejs (server side js), you can do it in NodeJS.

Comment: Hi, I wonder if JSONP can be a workaround so I don't need server-side script?

Answer (score 1):

You can't make this with javascript. You need a server-side script that downloads the page you need and then parse it with a DOM parser.

With PHP you can get the content of one URL with cURL.

See more:

http://php.net/manual/es/book.curl.php